# Disabling Dates in calendar in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a particular condition if which fulfills,
then if I click on my calendar UI image, a small popup calendar opens up but
with only last date of each month enabled. Rest all the dates are 
supposed to be disabled. But I have no idea how to enable only the last date
of each month as it is supposed to be kept dynamic as the last date of each month is different. So, delayedDates doesn't seem to be an option for me.